# downloading Microsoft Base Smart Card Cryptographic Service Provider Package for windows 7

Tags: windows, authentication, smartcard

The Base CSP can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=4670 . but it supports only windows xp. Can any once suggest, where it might be available?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Base Smart Card Cryptographic Service Provider is included as standard part of Windows 7 and newer.